# mod_rewrite and bootstrap modal

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, href, bootstrap-modal

I changed my website's URL with `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subdomain/ other_page.html [NC,L]
```

Now, my modal href's don't work anymore, which worked on index.html. This is modal href code:

```
<a href="#privacyPolicy" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">Privacy policy</a>
```

What's the problem? Do I have work with `mod_rewrite` or change `a href`? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you change the base path, you have to fix that, with:

```
<base href="/subdomain/">
```

or

```
<base href="http://www.domain.com/subdomain/">
```

in `<header>`

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.